# How to Check whether node exist or not

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

Below is my code . I am getting response of xml in responseElement and corredponding values.I want to know how can i check whether firstName/contactid node exist or not in following expression

```
var responseElement = XElement.Parse(putContactResponse);
ObjInvoice.Contact_Id = responseElement.XPathSelectElement("//Contact/ContactID").Value;
ObjInvoice.FirstName = responseElement.XPathSelectElement("//Contact/FirstName").Value;
```